# Spring Boot fastest way to deploy instead of build Jar?

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot from php world. In Php development, it is simple to make changes on the file, upload and run.

But on Spring boot, my development relies on remote ubuntu server, every time I make change in `*.java`, I have to build the Fat Jar, upload the Jar, kill the current java process on ubuntu, and run the `java -jar my.jar` again, which spend much time on the upload because the Jar is about 60 mb.

Is there any way I can work like php, just upload the changed file, so the spring boot just compile the class and run?

Does change to build `*.war` help to faster deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few option to mitigate the roundtrip of building the jar file and upload it.

**Hot-swap**: For *minor* changes, you can hot-swap changes automatially when you have a remote-debugger attached. I use Intellij as Ide, which provide this out of the box after a file is recompiled, see more at [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/altering-the-program-s-execution-flow.html#reload_classes) link how to enable it.

**Reloading tool**: use a tool that are designed to reload Java classes, such as *JRebel* which extends the classloader and updates a class if a change has been detected. However, they are often only available in a paid version.

**Spring Boot dev-tools**: this tool also monitors changes and restart the application with the new changes (so no need to rebuild the jar file). It is possible to use on a remote application. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools) link for more info.

Using a war file is different concept since a war file is executed inside an application container (e.g a Wildfly server). You can dynamically upload a war file to a running application server, which will only restart the war file. But I'm not sure if this will lead to faster deployment, however it is a different approach how the application is run.